# How to include dependent jar in maven jar

Tags: java, maven

I have two queries:

1) I have build a maven project and when I am tying to deploy jar on server it shows some error related to driver not found. Then I decompiled my jar and found that dependent database jar jconn jar is not in that. But I have that jar in my code and I am using following in my pom.xml to get that dependent jar with my jar but still it is not able to get dependent jar. Somewhere, I read on stackoverflow to add following to my pom.xml

```
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
<classpathPrefix>./</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.launcher.Main</mainClass>
  </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>​
```

Still it is giving the same thing and jconn jar was not in jar when decompiled. Please help.

2) I have some some key value pair in a property file and values are in comma separated form. I want to take all values of that key in a list. how can i do that. Please help

Comment: You want the shade plugin, not the assembly plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include other jars to your own ( it's called uber jar) you could use maven shade plugin

Example from their doc:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

It will create two jars. Original one with only yours content and uber with all other jars. It's possible to filter content, that will be included. For more examples please check:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html